# how to remove an element after the condition is met and return the new array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects and would like to compare start date of array 1 against array 2 to see if array 1 start date is within the range of array 2 start date and end date

1. Then also compare end date of array 1 against array 2 to see if array 1 end date is within the range of array 2 start date and end date

If both the condition above are met then validate if array 1 status is overlap.

eg: Dec 15-21 (array 1 - start date -end date ) Dec 18-31 (from array 2 start date -end date)

2. if array1 start date is outside the range of array 2 start and end date, then validate array 1 status is ready . and if array1 end date is outside the range of array 2 start and end date, then validate array 1 status is ready .

eg: Dec 01-07 (array 1 - start date -end date ) Dec 18-31 (from array 2 start date -end date)

3. If array 1 start date matches array 2 start date and array 1 end date matches array 2 end date then validate array 1 status is match,

eg: Dec 18-31 (array 1 - start date -end date ) Dec 18-31 (from array 2 start date -end date)

Firstly, I am comparing the month in the snippet so that dec months dates from array 1 are being compared only against dec month dates in array 2, likewise nov month dates from array 1 against nov month dates in array 2 etc. (this comparison works fine to validate all dec and nov month dates from array1)

Next, once date comparison is done for the matching months between array1 and array2(in this case dec and nov months are found in both array 1 and array2), I would like to return left out array objects from array 1 as a new array(say array3) in this case Jan, and Feb array objects.

**Just my thoughts:**

Overall, I want to return the final array that should remove all those elements(the array object) that satisfies any of the conditions ie if/else in the below code and return the new array at the end of the iteration.

The new array output should like the one mentioned below, and I can loop thru array3 and make sure that the rest of the array objects status is ready. (This is just my thought to extract Jan and feb months (as these months are not part of array2), and verify if all the other months except the ones found in array (in this case Dec and Nov) have the status as "ready".

(or) Please suggest if there is any better solution to verify the status of the array1 objects(jan,feb in this case) whose month is not found in array 2 and verify if the status is "ready".

**Final output should be :**

```
array3= [ {
    start_date: "2022-01-01",
    end_date: "2022-01-07",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-02-16",
    end_date: "2022-02-22",
  }]
```

My current code

```js
function compareTwoArrayOfObjects(array1, array2) {
  array2.map(element => {
    const start2 = new Date(element.start_date);
    const end2 = new Date(element.end_date);

    const start2Month = start2.getMonth();
    const end2Month = end2.getFullYear();

    console.log("####################################")
    return array1.map(elm_arr1 => {
      const start1 = new Date(elm_arr1.start_date);
      const end1 = new Date(elm_arr1.end_date);
      let status;

      const start1Month = start1.getMonth();
      const end1Month = end1.getFullYear();

      if (start1.getTime() === start2.getTime() && end1.getTime() === end2.getTime() && ((start1Month === start2Month) || (end1Month === start2Month))) {
        console.log("**************")
        status = "match";
        console.log(start1, end1)
        console.log(start2, end2)
        console.log(start1Month, start2Month)
        console.log(elm_arr1.status)
        //expect(elm_arr1.status).toMatch("match");
        console.log("**************")
      } else if (((start1Month === start2Month) || (end1Month === start2Month)) && ((start1 > start2 && start1 < end2) || (end1 > start2 && end1 < end2) || (start2 > start1 && start2 < end1) || (end2 > start1 && end2 < end1))) {
        status = "overlap";
        console.log("**************")
        console.log(start1, end1)
        console.log(start2, end2)
        console.log(start1Month, start2Month)
        console.log(elm_arr1.status)
        // expect(elm_arr1.status).toMatch("overlap");
        console.log("**************")
      } else if (((start1Month === start2Month) || (end1Month === start2Month)) && ((start1 < start2 && end1 < start2) || (start1 > end2 && end1 > end2))) {
        status = "ready";
        console.log("**************")
        console.log(start1, end1)
        console.log(start2, end2)
        console.log(start1Month, start2Month)
        console.log(elm_arr1.status)
        //expect(elm_arr1.status).toMatch("ready");
        console.log("**************")
      }
    });
  });
}

const result = compareTwoArrayOfObjects(array1, array2);
```

```html
<script>
  let array1 = [{
      start_date: "Dec 01 2022",
      end_date: "Dec 07 2022",
      status: "ready"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Dec 04 2022",
      end_date: "Dec 10 2022",
      status: "ready"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Dec 15 2022",
      end_date: "Dec 21 2022",
      status: "overlap"
    },

    {
      start_date: "Dec 18 2022",
      end_date: "Dec 24 2022",
      status: "overlap"
    },

    {
      start_date: "Dec 12 2022",
      end_date: "Dec 28 2022",
      status: "overlap"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Dec 25 2022",
      end_date: "Dec 31 2022",
      status: "overlap"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Nov 22 2022",
      end_date: "Nov 28 2022",
      status: "match"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Nov 01 2022",
      end_date: "Nov 07 2022",
      status: "ready"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Jan 01 2022",
      end_date: "Jan 07 2022",
      status: "ready"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Feb 16 20226",
      end_date: "Feb 22 2022",
      status: "ready"
    },
  ];

  let array2 = [{
      start_date: "Dec 18 2022",
      end_date: "Dec 31 2022"
    },
    {
      start_date: "Nov 22 2022",
      end_date: "Nov 28 2022"
    },
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's that bit that's `undefined`? You're not returning anything from the main function which _would_ return `undefined`. Note also: both `map` and `filter` return _new_ arrays - they don't work in place.

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` and then paste the script into something that will be a [mcve] - your code is not valid - the timestamps need to be quoted, `let array1 = Main value:` is not valid JS and your `---->`  needs to be comments

Comment: i did add return in the first map now i see it returned the values. Can you please advise how to handle this scenario , how to remove the element that meets if/else condition in order to get the new array? am i not supposed to use filter here? if not  can you suggest any better solution to handle the above scenario?

Comment: sure, Thank you, i will stop editing.

Comment: I want to return the final array 1 after removing the element(remove the whole array object) that meets /satisfies the if/else condition , I want to return the final array that should remove those element( the whole object array) that do satisfy any of the conditions ie if/else in the code and return the final array

Comment: @mplungjan sorry, not sure if i you have posted an answer, I am unable to see it incase you posted it. and thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I did not because I could not run the code

Comment: @mplungjan, the snippet at the top runs ok , that you can use to implement your changes, I clicked on edit then [<>] and ran the code snippet that is at the top and it  executed without an error, do you mind checking the code snippet at the very top and add your changes to it?

Comment: Perhaps tomorrow. I am not the only one around

Comment: This makes NO sense. It will NEVER be true `elm_arr1.startDate != elm_arr1.startDate`

Comment: ok,I removed the above piece of code and added a comment instead to explain what i am looking for, Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry. You are confusing me. Which snippet is yours and which is a cut and paste from another question? What is your input data and what is expected output data. Please help use help you and create ***[mcve]*** without any extra unnecessary stuff

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry for the confusion, I updated the details above, and described what i am looking for. Looking forward to hear from you. Please let me know if any question, and Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I have rearranged and formatted your code. It is a HUGE amount of description. I still do not know your current output other than a load of console.log. What is the CURRENT output and why is it not what you expect? Can you shorten this text?

Comment: Just use Array.prototype.filter to remove elem and returns new array

Comment: I did shorten the text, hope it helps,Final output should be this , array3= [ {
    start_date: "2022-01-01",
    end_date: "2022-01-07",
  },
  {
    start_date: "2022-02-16",
    end_date: "2022-02-22",
  }]  , I am trying to get this as the final output  which is the exact issue i am trying to address here, not sure how i can update the code to return this output,  as of now i am just printing console.log just for readability to help anyone understand how the above snippet works.